# POST jpeg upload with AFNetworking

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, http, afnetworking

I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work when I use AFNetworking. It worked with ASIHTTP. This is all very new to me. But I can't figure out why the files are not being transferred from $_FILES to the server's HD anymore. Here's the iOS code:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPressed 
{
[self.fileName resignFirstResponder];
NSURL *remoteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com"];

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSString *photoName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf-Photo.jpeg",timeInterval];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// the path to write file
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
NSData * photoImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.remoteImage.image, 1.0);
[photoImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"photo written to path: e%@", filePath);

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:remoteUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                       path:@"/photos" 
                                                                 parameters:nil 
                                                  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
                                  {
                                      [formData appendPartWithFormData:[self.fileName.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                                                  name:@"name"];


                                      [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData 
                                                                  name:self.fileName.text 
                                                              fileName:filePath 
                                                              mimeType:@"image/jpeg"]; 
                                  }
                                  ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];

   [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Gives a very scary warning
}];

[operation start];    



}
```

I used to do this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:remoteUrl];
[request setPostValue:self.fileName.text forKey:@"name"];
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"filename"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Here's my PHP:

```
 {
// these could be stored in a .ini file and loaded
// via parse_ini_file()... however, this will suffice
// for an example
$codes = Array(
    100 => 'Continue',
    101 => 'Switching Protocols',
    200 => 'OK',
    201 => 'Created',
    202 => 'Accepted',
    203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
    204 => 'No Content',
    205 => 'Reset Content',
    206 => 'Partial Content',
    300 => 'Multiple Choices',
    301 => 'Moved Permanently',
    302 => 'Found',
    303 => 'See Other',
    304 => 'Not Modified',
    305 => 'Use Proxy',
    306 => '(Unused)',
    307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
    400 => 'Bad Request',
    401 => 'Unauthorized',
    402 => 'Payment Required',
    403 => 'Forbidden',
    404 => 'Not Found',
    405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
    406 => 'Not Acceptable',
    407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
    408 => 'Request Timeout',
    409 => 'Conflict',
    410 => 'Gone',
    411 => 'Length Required',
    412 => 'Precondition Failed',
    413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
    414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
    415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
    416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
    417 => 'Expectation Failed',
    500 => 'Internal Server Error',
    501 => 'Not Implemented',
    502 => 'Bad Gateway',
    503 => 'Service Unavailable',
    504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
    505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
);

return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
header($status_header);
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
echo $body;
}

if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_POST["name"])) {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
            $uploads_dir = '/var/www/cnet/photos';
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name.jpg");
            $result = array("SUCCEEDED");
            sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
            } else {

            sendResponse(400, 'Nope');
            }
?>
```

Comment: Some comments: you should use `!empty($_FILES)` instead of `isset($_FILES)` & `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']` will return the full path to the uploaded file, so move_uploaded_file would not work, if you added `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your php file then you would see the error...

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and made the change from isset to !empty. And turned on error_reporting. But this is from my iPhone to the server. I don't know where I should see the errors.

And regarding the move_uploaded_files syntax, I pulled that straight from the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php.

Comment: I fixed the php code and ran it with the old ASIHTTPFormRequest version of my app. It still works like that. The problem is definitely in the AFNetworking implementation here.

Answer (score 13):

Try this snippet of code:

```
    NSData* sendData = [self.fileName.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *sendDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sendData forKey:@"name"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:remoteUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                           path:@"/photos" 
                                                                     parameters:sendDictionary 
                                                      constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
                                      {                                     
                                          [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData 
                                                                      name:self.fileName.text 
                                                                  fileName:filePath 
                                                                  mimeType:@"image/jpeg"]; 
                                      }
                                      ];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

        NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Gives a very scary warning
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: But if there is some way to use it without warning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with what ASI is doing with `setPostValue:forKey:`, but you may be missing a `name` parameter to be sent separately from the image upload.

What does either the client or server log, exactly? Is the progress block logging?

A few other points:

- You can just do `[operation start]` at the end; no need to create an operation queue for just that.
- To help with logging, set `completionBlock` on `operation`, with an `NSLog` of the response, or something like that.
- You may want to create an `AFHTTPClient` base class with a class method to return a singleton instance, like the Gowalla API client in the AFNetworking example app. That client can then manage a single operation queue for all of your network requests.

Comment: I adjusted the code above to be most recent. Verified that the PHP works. I am trying to do the completion block but it won't let me log operation.responsString. What should I put in the block instead?

Comment: Ach! I got the completion block to work. It's giving me "Nope" which means they are at least communicating to each other. But I'm getting a 400 response. So the code says that either $_FILES is empty or $_POST['name'] is not set. I also added in the @"name" appendPartWithFormData. You can see above all the most recent of both.

So this form data is not being sent just right yet.

Comment: After we update to 2.0, there is no AFHTTPClient and using Igor Fedorchuk's code gets an warning, any new apis?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround using NSMutableURLRequest:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:remoteUrl];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data, boundary=%@", boundary];
[req setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

//adding the body:
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\";\r\nfilename=\"china.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setHTTPBody:postBody];
```