# How to upload multiple file in background using AFNetworking Library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

Right now , I am following this link http://pastebin.com/Xu6sh6TY and [iPhone upload multipart file using AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410689/iphone-upload-multipart-file-using-afnetworking) 
for uploading file . But I want to upload large no of file in background.and also handle the suspended event if connection lost or app is closed by click on Home button by user.then when app come in foreground then my uploading process automatically resume.

Please guide me .how to implement uploading of multiple file using afnetworking library in background .And Background process using afnetworking is support for both ioS6 and iOS7?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Best place to start is by reading the AFNetworking documentation and looking at the examples.

Comment: Thanks for comment Sir. But I didn't find out more details on uploading file in background.Please give clue