# Image upload time out error in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, upload, server

I use the below code to upload image to server.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.250.1.52:xxx/api/user/profileUploadUser?userid=27&emailid=tom@gnts.in"];

 NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[jsonDict setObject:ImageToUpload forKey:@"file"];

////////ImageToUpload = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/89112E0B-C1D6-4408-8586-6C5B4A431713/Documents/61.png

    [manager POST:url parameters:jsonDict
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     { //////success code }


         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image upload" message:@"failure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
             NSLog(@"error message  %@",error);
             // handle failure
         }];
```

It always enter into the failure block and
 shows the error message.

> error message :  Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request
>   timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.250.1.52:xxxx/api/user/profileUploadUser?userid=27&emailid=tom@gnts.in, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-21022}}}

Comment: use multiform data for upload the image to server

Comment: Is it possible to send file path of image using multiform data.

Comment: file path is dynamic, how will u extract the same

Comment: I use the dynamic file path in code. I put the path here for showing that I want to upload file path to server.

Comment: ok then `file` is used for upload the image not a path

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet speed might be slow,

```
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:30];//Set request timeout interval time & interact with backend developer for same.
```

One more thing you can manage one `retry counter` in `singleton` & give second request if fails & if again fails then show toast message internet speed is slow.

Comment: It's upto you how many time you have to give request & don't forget to reset `retryCounter` to 0 again in both condition(I mean reset retryCounter to zero once you in success block or show error toast message)

Comment: I put the timeout interval code here, but it's not solve my issue.  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval=30;

Comment: Set time interval to 60 & check & even not worked then you can manage one `retryCounter' singleton give request twice & even if fails you have to handle toast message that **Try Again, Request Time Out** its because of internet speed issue. I don't think issue is different rather than internet speed & please for request interval time you can discuss one time with backend developer. if you got another solution let me know

Comment: Ohh it seems you are uploading file only. Visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413152/4294543

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I use the code from above url, But it shows error "unrecognizes selector"      NSURL *localFileToUpload = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageToUpload];
    
   
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    
    [manager POST:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:localFileToUpload
                                    name:@"files"
                                fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

Comment: make sure you are correctly retain/release objects make zombie state enable from edit scheme go to diagonosis & allow all obj-c exceptions .... this will help you to track your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to a `POST` operation whereas what you want is a `file upload`. 
Try out *AFNetworking multipart* file upload.