# post request changing image name iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

how to change the name of the image??Actually I want to append the phone number from user at image name to make a unique name for image

below is my action button code

```
NSString *filename =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache",self.tmpp1];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profilei.image, 1.0);

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


// add params (all params are strings
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@\r\n\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", @"image"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add image data
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpg\r\n", @"imageFormKey"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

//  parameter username
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"customer_name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"%@",_nametf.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

the phone number is store in the string mobilestrp and I want to append coz my server accept is if it has the number.Thanks in advance for any suggestions!!

Comment: why you are not using afnetworking ???

Comment: @matloobHasnain it was from another code and the said it was obj c and this can be used

Comment: @matloobHasnain what do u suggest I shud use??

Comment: I will suggest use Afnetworking , Its very easy to use and gives with blocks.

Comment: do u have any sample code??for my reference @matloobHasnain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410689/iphone-upload-multipart-file-using-afnetworking

Comment: should we import any files ??@matloobHasnain I am getting error

Comment: Yes please read Afnetworking first https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking