# iOS AFNetworking GET/POST Parameters

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I want to do a POST request with AFNetworking which contains GET and POST parameters.

I am using this code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload_stuff.php?userGUID=%@&clientGUID=%@",
                           @"1234",
                           [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString];

    NSString *newUrl = @"https://sub.domain.com";

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary *getParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"1234", @"userGUID",
                            [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString, @"clientGUID",
                            nil];
    NSDictionary *postParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [@"xyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], @"FILE",
                                nil];

    [httpClient postPath:urlString parameters:postParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
    }];
```

Now I have two questions:

- How can I use BOTH GET and POST dictionaries in the same request? For the time, I am integrating the GET dictionary into the URL and using only the POST dictionary (`[httpClient postPath:...]`)
- I am getting an error from the server stating that the parameter "FILE" is missing. Unfortunately I can't examine any server logs (not my server). But using a standard `NSURLConnection` I was able to send requests with the `FILE` parameter to this server. So what is going wrong here?

Comment: Afnetworking has its own method for sending file

Comment: Can you give any Code?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow for you:

```
NSData* sendData = [self.fileName.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *sendDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sendData forKey:@"name"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:remoteUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                       path:@"/photos" 
                                                                 parameters:sendDictionary 
                                                  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
                                  {                                     
                                      [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData 
                                                                  name:self.fileName.text 
                                                              fileName:filePath 
                                                              mimeType:@"image/jpeg"]; 
                                  }
                                  ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Gives a very scary warning
}];

[operation start];
```

By @Igor Fedorchuk from [POST jpeg upload with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557364/post-jpeg-upload-with-afnetworking)

Comment: The answer has no relationship with get arguments. It wasted my life.

Comment: Actually, I don't think GET method can send file directly. If i am wrong, plz tell me.

This lazy answer is posted as @user1423640's request. It is not an answer for GET method.

If you really want to send it by GET method, change the image to base64 and send it. (Take note to the limited length)

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking has no method to setup both GET and POST params.
You have to setup GET params to your url, and use `[AFHTTPClient requestWithMethod:path:parameters:]` setup POST params.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)requestForPath:(NSString *)path method:(NSString *)method
{
    NSMutableString *pathWithGetParams = [NSMutableString stringWithString:path];
    BOOL hasPathContainsQueryChar = [path rangeOfString:@"?"].location != NSNotFound;
    [pathWithGetParams appendString:hasPathContainsQueryChar ? @"&" : @"?"];
    for (id key in self.getArguments.allKeys)
    {
        if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSString *value = self.getArguments[key];
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                [pathWithGetParams appendString:[[self class] urlEncode:key]];
                [pathWithGetParams appendString:@"="];
                [pathWithGetParams appendString:[[self class] urlEncode:value]];
                [pathWithGetParams appendString:@"&"];
            }
        }
    }

    NSString *upperCaseMethod = [method uppercaseString];
    BOOL isMethodInGet = [upperCaseMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[self shareAFClient] requestWithMethod:method
                                                               path:pathWithGetParams
                                                         parameters:isMethodInGet ? nil : self.postArguments];
    return request;
}

+ (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)stringToEncode
{
    return [self urlEncode:stringToEncode usingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

+ (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)stringToEncode usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                 (__bridge CFStringRef)stringToEncode,
                                                                                 NULL,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                                                 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}

+ (NSString*)urlDecode:(NSString *)stringToDecode
{
    return [self urlDecode:stringToDecode usingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

+ (NSString*)urlDecode:(NSString *)stringToDecode usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                                                                  (__bridge CFStringRef)stringToDecode,
                                                                                                  (CFStringRef)@"",
                                                                                                  CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```